# value of a value in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to write a shell script to display the values of the environment variables passed as positional parameters.

```
for i in $@
do
printf "$i" | xargs -I {} echo "${}"
done
```

However, the above code doesn't work.
Could someone guide me through.

Thanks.

Comment: The first argument to `printf` should be a format string, like `"%s\n"`.

Comment: The double quotes around `"${}"` cause the running shell to try to expand it and fail. (I get a "bad substitution" error here.) In addition to the points discussed in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your script is that `xargs` doesn't use the shell to execute the command, so `$` in an argument doesn't cause variable expansion.

Instead, use indirect variable references, by putting `!` before the variable name, as described in the [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) documentation.

```
for i in "$@"
do
    printf "%s = %s\n" "$i" "${!i}"
done
```

Result:

```
$ ./testvar.sh HOME USER
HOME = /Users/barmar
USER = barmar
```

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` doesn't run the command through a shell therefore positional arguments  don't expand.

You can use `bash -c` to execute `echo` command and expand the positional arguments:

```
for i in "$@"; do
   echo "$i" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo "${}"'
done
```

Comment: You shouldn't expand the argument from `xargs` into a shell script directly. It isn't safe.

Comment: `echo` is also an executable: `/bin/echo`. The built-in is just an optimization.

Comment: The real explanation is that `xargs` doesn't run the command through a shell, so `$` doesn't cause variable expansion.

Comment: @EtanReisner: How is this not safe? Can you give an example input?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Pipe `echo 'HOME\"; ls /tmp\"'` to the `xargs` invocation in this answer and see what happens. `{}` expands to a single word in the command to be run (so it is safe on its own) but when that command is a string run by the shell you lose that safety. You need to pass it as an *argument* to the shell script to be safe. (e.g. `bash -c 'echo "${!1}"' - {}`) Which, in this case, means it doesn't work for what is desired (without involving indirect expansion in which case the `printf`/`xargs` isn't necessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner: So what's the env. var input in this case? MCVE please.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't understand the question. The env var being printed by name isn't the issue here. The input to `xargs` is. The OP is processing arguments (to a function or script presumably).

Comment: @EtanReisner: how do you invoke this script to get the security problem?

Comment: Feed it the string `HOME\"; ls /tmp\"` as an argument. Well, not the OP's version which blows up spaces in the arguments but this version.